# Soft-require a feature, then conditionally run more commands

Tags: require

What's the idiomatic Emacs way to soft-require a feature, then use that feature if it's available?

The [`require` function allows “soft require”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#index-require) by specifying a non-nil third argument:

```lisp
(require 'projectile nil 'missing-okay)
```

What's the best way to then use that feature to do more things, only if the feature is now present?

```lisp
(if succeeds
 (require 'projectile nil 'missing-okay)
 (do-some-stuff-that-needs-projectile))
```

or

```lisp
(require 'projectile nil 'missing-okay)
(when feature-is-available 'projectile
 (do-some-stuff-that-needs-projectile))
```

or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just test with `featurep`:

```lisp
(require 'projectile nil t)
(when (featurep 'projectile)
 (do-some-stuff-that-needs-projectile))
```

or you use that the `require` returns nil if it is not possible to load:

```lisp
(when (require 'projectile nil t)
  (do-some-stuff-that-needs-projectile)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the latter - the best idiom for this.

Comment: Both of those work exactly as I want, thank you.